# OnClickListener in TextInputEditText wrapped around TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, datepickerdialog

I have got a **TextInputEditText** wrapped around a **TextInputLayout**, as Google recommends to do: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

However, my TextInputEditText has an OnClickListener set on it so when it gets tapped by the User, a DatePickerDialog can popup.

My issue is that in fact, on the first tap nothing happens apart from the hint label to move above the TextInputEditText.
On second tap, the DatePickerDialog is shown.

How could I get that DatePickerDialog to show up on first tap?
Setting the onClickListener on the TextInutLayout instead of the TextInputEditText does not work.
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: can you put some of your code here

Comment: What code? It's just a basic XML with a **TextInputLayout** wrapping a **TextInputEditText** and on the Java side a simple **OnClickListener** set on the **TextInputEditTex**t.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The calendar opening only on the second click is because you are using an `edittext`. On the first click, your Edit Text will get focus. then the second click only calls the onClickListener.

If you are not looking forward to edit the date set manually (using keyboard), then why not using a TextView to display the selected Date?.

**Show Calendar on First Click :**

If you need to use EditText and load the calender in the first click, then try setting an `onFocusChangeListner` to the editText instead of `onClickListner`.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
           // Show your calender here 
        } else {
           // Hide your calender here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate, I will implement it tomorrow when I get back to work and flag your respond right if it works.
To answer your question: **why not using a TextView to display the selected Date?** Well you know, those monkeys from the UX/Design Team...

Comment: @AndyStrife Ok Then `setOnFocusChangeListener` on `EditTetext` that is work on single click to Show Calendar.

Answer (score 8):

Set the attribute android:focusableInTouchMode to false, like this:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in your edittext xml code.
For more information, visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42470061/6899791)

Comment: This works as well - and depending on your solution this could be the better solution.

In my case I did a custom view called TextInputLayoutWithEditText that allows me to set a click listener and then internally calls 

getEditText().setFocusable(false);

before passing the listener to the edit text - this works surprisingly well.

Answer (score 1):

I answered the linked question with an improved solution that does not affect keyboard navigation but still allows you to have the desired focus behaviour.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62875800/9901599, but the crux of it is to not set any focus-related XML attributes, and do this in code:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, isFocused ->
    if (view.isInTouchMode && isFocused) {
        view.performClick()  // picks up first tap
    }
}
editText.setOnClickListener {
    showDatePicker() // the actual thing you want to do
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted since it solves the problem perfectly. I had the same problem as in the question and this is the the solution I am using. Have I missed something?

Comment: this solve a problem when (UX Experience) user have already picker datetime then want to pick against by click TextInputEditText.  for example ```        _bindingIs.txtTglBerangkat.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
            if (b)
                pickDateTime(_bindingIs.txtTglBerangkat)
        }
        _bindingIs.txtTglBerangkat.setOnClickListener {
            pickDateTime(_bindingIs.txtTglBerangkat)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to set:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

To `TextInputEditText` or `EditText`

And use:

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    showDatePicker();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

It will also avoid showing the cursor in the edittext field.