# EditText inside TextInputLayout onclick requires 2 click ?! Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am simply trying to have an onlick listen on an Edit text inside a TextInputLayout. It works but I need to click on the EditText twice for it to trigger I dont understand why. Here is my code:

xml:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/start_date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Starting Date*: "
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Listenner:

```
   private void setListenners() {
        EditText startDate = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.start_date);
        startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "year: " + year + " month: " + month + " day: " + day);
                    }
                },mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Consider using a `Fragment` over `Dialog`, since it's very easy to leak a `Dialog`. For example, if the user, having a dialog shown, taps the menu button (hides the app), then Activity gets destroyed by the system, and after that the user starts the app again, this causes _Activity has leaked window_ error.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Set the attribute **`android:focusableInTouchMode`** to **false**

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in your `edittext` xml code.

---

Explanation, as from docs, [`android:focusableInTouchMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusableInTouchMode) is:

> Boolean that controls whether a view can take focus while in touch
>   mode. If this is true for a view, that view can gain focus when
>   clicked on, and can keep focus if another view is clicked on that
>   doesn't have this attribute set to true.

and the `EditText` is *true* by default.

In other words: the first click will make the `edittext` to gain focus and second click is the one that triggers the `ClickListener`. So you should disable gaining focus on touch.

Comment: @Rémi you're welcome, please consider accepting it as answer for other people who may come through  you question.

Comment: If you long click on the input, you will be able to paste your last copied text, so this is not a full solution.

Comment: @NabilSouk your situation is not part of OP's question. if you have a separate question feel free to search on `SO` or post new question if you did not find what you aim for.

Comment: @NabilSouk To get the default behaviour you need to add this within the onClickListener: startDate.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); startDate.requestFocus();

Answer (score 6):

I found an alternative solution which suited my needs better than the other answer. Basically you set the onClickListener as normal, but you add an OnFocusChangedListener to pick up the first tap (when gaining focus). This only activates in touch mode so doesn't affect keyboard navigation.

You don't need to set any XML attributes related to focus, just use the following code (it's kotlin btw):

```
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, isFocused ->
        if (view.isInTouchMode && isFocused) {
            view.performClick()  // picks up first tap
        }
    }
    editText.setOnClickListener {
        showDatePicker() // the actual thing you want to do
    }
```

This method has the advantage that the view will remain focused (and if you are using a `TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` style, it will remain highlighted) even after the DatePicker is dismissed. This does not happen when you set `focusableInTouchMode = false`.

Once the view is focused, future taps will trigger only the OnClickListener, so it won't be called again by the `FocusChangeListener` calling `performClick()`. (I checked this with the debugger on API 29)