# TextInputEditText needs 2 taps to fire the associated listener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-datepicker, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have a view with some input fields, one of those is a `TextInputEditText` with a `datepicker` associated which shows up when the field is selected. The problem is that at the first tap, the `TextInputEditText` field gets the focus and it is required a second tap do show the `datepicker`.

This is how the field is defined

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/wExpiresAt"
    style="@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Text.ErrorText"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Text.HintText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wMessage">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/tvExpiresAt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/tv_pick_date_ph"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

While inside the activity:

```
val mExpiresAt: TextInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.tvExpiresAt)

mExpiresAt!!.setOnClickListener {
    val cal   = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year  = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day   = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    val dialog = DatePickerDialog(
            this@NewMessageActivity,
            android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
            mDateSetListener,
            year, month, day)
    dialog.show()        
}
```

My guess is that the problem is caused by the `TextInputLayout` which wraps the `TextInputEditText`, the first tap fires the animation which moves the hint string from the text field to its top and gives the focus to the field itself, the second tap fires the listener associated to the text field and the `datepicker` appears. How can I get all the events on the first tap?

Comment: try android:clickable="false" on wExpiresAt

Comment: @Satya that didn't work, but thanks to your suggestion I've thought to set `android:focusable="false"` to tvExpiresAt and that did the job.

Comment: May be this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62875800/6795274

Answer (score 0):

Just set for editText. It allows for a view to handle click and focus at the same time!

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```